# React Native read pdf417 barcode from image

Tags: react-native, camera, pdf417

I need to read a pdf417 barcode from a taken photo with React Native. I tried [react-native-camera](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera), but it only reads barcodes from camera. Have anyone used another library to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to decode barcode from image(if I understood correctly your problem), **react-native-camera** *does not support*  this feature. A good alternative for this will be Barcode recognition tools in JS. For instance, have a look at [this link](https://gist.github.com/tobytailor/421369) and demos in it.

Good luck